# npx react-native run-android --deviceId build failing

Tags: android, react-native

When I am trying to run my app in android emulator, the app build is successful and app runs in emulator.

But when I try to run the app from local to a connected android device,
npx react-native run-android --deviceId
the build is failing.

```
> Task :react-native-fetch-blob:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
> Task :react-native-file-opener:verifyReleaseResources FAILED                                                            

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
```

```
 ERROR:C:\mobile\node_modules\react-native-file-opener\android\build\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:2585: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/endY not found.

  ERROR:C:\mobile\node_modules\react-native-file-opener\android\build\intermediates\merged_res\release\values\values.xml:2554: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
```

My device is an android 10 mobile.

Can anyone please guide of what error I am doing

Comment: ```npx react-native run-android```should start the app on the attached device.

Comment: @MichaelBahl I tried "npx react-native run-android" device ID, but then still it fails when I give android phone id, but the build is successful when it is via emulator

Comment: Check with ```adb devices``` if the attached device were found.

You don't need to add a device id for android device just execute ```npx react-native run-android```

Comment: @MichaelBahl yes in the listed devices the device was shown and I ran without the device id this time. Got many errors and build failed. 

`Unable to install C:\projects\dev-mobile\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE
        at com.android.ddmlib.internal.DeviceImpl.installRemotePackage(DeviceImpl.java:1315)`

Comment: Is the app already installed on your device? If yes uninstall the app on your device.

Comment: @MichaelBahl Yes I have an app center version installed in the device and not the local one, does that get affected?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the ```applicationId``` and the```versionCode```
You can delete your Appcenter version or bump the versionCode to override the Appcenter version or use another applicationId for debug versions.